# Bootstrap button loading text with Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In a non-angular application that uses bootstrap and jquery, I can create buttons like this:

```
<button id="saveButton" data-loading-text="Please wait...">Save</button>
```

Then, when the button is clicked, I can set it to it's loading state like this:

```
$('#saveButton').button('loading');
```

Clicking this button also fires an ajax request, and in the callback for that request, I can reset the button like this:

```
$('#saveButton').button('reset');
```

How can I accomplish this same behavior within an angular application? The application also includes Jquery and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your angularjs application,
inside your view:

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search()">{{ searchButtonText }}
    </button>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.searchButtonText = "Search";

$scope.search = function() {
     $scope.searchButtonText = "Searching";
    // Do your searching here
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc6nx235/)
Hope this is what you want to implement.

Comment: This works, but seems like it could get messy quickly in a large application with lots of buttons as well as additional behavior that needs to occur during and after the saving process.  Having to constantly put the application in a loading and non-state seems complicated.  I was hoping to find a way to solve this using directives. I will mark your answer as accepted and ask a new question specifically about directives.

Comment: Yes, you can use this way if you have few buttons on a page. If you wish, you can create custom directive according to your requirement.

Comment: is not just changing the text is also disabling the button.

Comment: Have the the same issue like OP. This is some sort of solution. But if you want to use also html inside the searchButtonText e.g. a loader icon. Then this doesn't work.

Answer (score 13):

The advantage of using `data-loading-text` is to keep the HTML out of the controller.  Instead of swapping the text in a controller function, use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` inside the button:

```
<button>
    <span ng-hide="saving">Save</span>
    <span ng-show="saving">Please wait...</span>
</button>
```

In the controller, set `$scope.saving` to true or false.

```
$scope.saving = false;
$scope.save = function() {
    $scope.saving = true;
    // Do your saving here
    $scope.saving = false;
}
```

If you want to disable the button while it is loading, use `ng-disabled`.  To use a spinning FontAwesome icon, replace the `<span>` with the `<i>` tag as shown here:

```
 <button ng-disabled="saving">
    <span ng-hide="loading">Save</span>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="saving"></i>
</button>
```